# Cannot insert the value NULL into column , table ; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I found many similar questions on SO, I tried said resolutions but none of those worked for me, can anyone tell me what was wrong in following code, what corrections needs to be made to make it workable:

> Models:

```
public class ParentDataClassData
    {
        public ParentDataClassData()
        {
            TitleSetTitles = new List<ChildDataClass1>();
            TitlesSetEvents = new List<ChildDataClass2>();
        }

        public virtual int TitleSetID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ChildDataClass1> TitleSetTitles { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<ChildDataClass2> TitlesSetEvents { get; set; }

        public virtual object IdentityField
        {
            get { return TitleSetID; }
        }
    }


public class ChildDataClass1
    {
        public ChildDataClass1()
        {
            TitleSet = new ParentDataClassData();
            TitleSetTitleEventMedias = new List<TitleSetTitleEventMediaData>();
        }

        public virtual int TitleSetID
        {
            get { return TitleSet.TitleSetID; }
        }

        public virtual ParentDataClassData TitleSet { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<TitleSetTitleEventMediaData> TitleSetTitleEventMedias { get; set; }

        public virtual object IdentityField
        {
            get { return TitleSetTitleID; }
        }

    }


 public class ChildDataClass2
    {
        public virtual ParentDataClassData TitleSet { get; set;  }

        public virtual int TitleSetEventID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public virtual object IdentityField
        {
            get { return TitleSetEventID; }
        }
    }
```

> Mappings:

```
public class ParentDataClassMap : ClassMap<ParentDataEntity>
    {
        public ParentDataClassMap()
        {
            Table("TitleSet");

            LazyLoad();

            Id(x => x.TitleSetID)
                .Column("TitleSetID")
                .GeneratedBy.Native()
                .UnsavedValue(0);


            HasMany(x => x.TitleSetTitles)
            .LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Fetch.Subselect()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .KeyColumn("TitleSetID");

            HasMany(x => x.TitlesSetEvents)
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
                .Fetch.Subselect()
                .KeyColumn("TitleSetID");
        }
    }


 public class ChildDataClass1Map : ClassMap<ChildDataClass1>
    {
        public ChildDataClass1Map()
        {
            Table("TitleSetTitle");

            Id(x => x.TitleSetTitleID)
                .Column("TitleSetTitleID")
                .GeneratedBy.Native()
                .UnsavedValue(0);

            References(x => x.TitleSet)
                .Fetch.Join()
                .Not.Nullable()
                .Column("TitleSetID")
                .Cascade.None();


            HasMany(x => x.TitleSetTitleEventMedias)
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Fetch.Subselect()
                .KeyColumn("TitleSetTitleID");
        }
}


 public class ChildDataClass2Map : ClassMap<ChildDataClass2>
    {
        public ChildDataClass2Map()
        {
            Table("TitleSetEvent");

            Id(x => x.TitleSetEventID)
                .Column("TitleSetEventID")
                .GeneratedBy.Native()
                .UnsavedValue(0);


            References(x => x.TitleSet)
                .Column("TitleSetID")
                .Not.Update()
                .Not.Insert()
                .Cascade.None();

            Map(x => x.LengthSec).Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.EventID).Not.Nullable();

            HasMany(x => x.TitleSetDefaultEventMedia)
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.None()
                .Fetch.Join()
                .KeyColumn("TitleSetEventID");

            HasMany(x => x.TitleSetTitleEventMedias)
                .LazyLoad()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.None()
                .Fetch.Join()
                .KeyColumn("TitleSetEventID");
        }
    }
```

> Test:

```
[Test]
        public void CanAddNewTitleSet()
        {
            var titleSet = new TitleSetDataEntity
                {
                    Name = "Somename",
                    ProgramServiceID = 1,
                    CreatedBy = "someuser",
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ModifiedBy = "someuser",
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    TitleSetTitles = new List<TitleSetTitleData>
                    {
                        new TitleSetTitleData
                        {
                            IsIncluded = true,
                            IsPremiere = true,
                            TitleTypeCode = "somecode",
                        }
                    },
                    TitlesSetEvents = new List<TitleSetEventData>()
                };


                Session.SaveOrUpdate(titleSet);

            }
```

and getting exception:

> NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: ERROR
>   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher [(null)] -  Could not execute query:
>   INSERT INTO TitleSetTitle ([TitleID], ..., TitleSetID)  VALUES (@p0,
>   @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):  Cannot insert the
>   value NULL into column 'TitleSetID', table 'TitleSetTitle'; column
>   does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

**P.S.**

1. I used inverse as of bidirectional mappings
2. Anyhow inverse does not obey the things, per my understanding it should save `ParantClassData` first to make sure `Child` classes get proper ids.
3. Not sure, what I missed

Any help for above issue will be warmly appreciated!

**Update**
Added more info to explain the issue, instead of lengthy code, I am just wondering if anyhow `TitleSetID` readonly property pertaining issue.

Comment: Stop trying to put a null value into `TitleSetID`?

Comment: Reduce the code to the smallest example that displays the error. You're trying to insert NULL into `TitleSetID` or you've not included `TitleSetID` in the insert list.

Comment: I am not supply any null value to `TitleSetID`, see my test, just trying to insert new collection.

Comment: See answer from @DanielKelley. Main issue is in its description and not in its Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in fact is hidden in this mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x.TitleSetTitles)
    ...
    .Inverse();
```

This mapping is instructing NHibernate:

> The chlild will care about this relation.

But that means, that child must know about its parent. which is not true in this code:

```
var titleSet = new TitleSetDataEntity
{
    Name = "Somename",
    ...
    TitleSetTitles = new List<TitleSetTitleData>
    {
        new TitleSetTitleData...
    },
};
session.Save(titleSet);
```

In this code, the child instance created by `new TitleSetTitleData` is missing the parent reference! And that's the problem

*NOTE - I guess that the property TitleSetTitles is of type `IList<ChildDataClass1> TitleSetTitles` but in the code we use `new List<TitleSetTitleData>` ... I guess it is a typo*

The correct syntax would be:

```
var titleSet = new TitleSetDataEntity
{
    Name = "Somename",
    ...
    TitleSetTitles = new List<TitleSetTitleData>();
};
var child = new TitleSetTitleData
{
    ...
    ParentDataClassData = titleSet,
};
titleSet.TitleSetTitles.Add(child);
session.Save(titleSet);
```

And now, NHibernate will have enough information. `Parent` has a `Child` added in the list, `Child` knows about the `Parent` and `.Inverse()` mapping will work, **because the ID of Parent won't be null anymore**

Comment: this is there is model: object IdentityField. I cant change the schema of table as this is a legacy app. Also, I verified this column if an Identity column in Table TitleSet.

Comment: I updated my answer, it should clearly show you, that we need to set both sides of relation parent-child. If this will be set, all SQL statements will be processed correctly...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried but still same error, I also referred this:http://nanovazquez.com/2013/07/04/playing-with-nhibernate-inverse-and-cascade/ but no worth, anyhow `TitleSetID` is everytime null and its only when I try to save `TitleSet` with its children like `TitleSetTitles`, if there are no children collections then it works fine, it is happening only when I tried to save it with both Parent and Children.

Comment: My tests passed now. I am looking into my actual things hope all will go fine, I marked +1 your answer as your answer is really beneficial, I appreciated your time spent on this conversation. Regarding down-vote to my question, I am not sure, why guys are not looking to actual issue, I believe they just read question not description, hope I could ask this to moderator of SO, anyways, you helped me a lot.

Comment: GREAT Job, sir! Please, do not give up, because of few questionable down votes... Enjoy NHibernate...brilliant tool ;)

Answer (score -1):

Errors like these usually occur whenever you attempt to insert a NULL value into a column, or you forget to include a column in the insert statement, as some column settings require data and cannot be left blank. Make sure you're including `TitleSetID` in the insert statement and you're putting a non-NULL value into it.

Comment: I am simply trying to insert collection, see my test `TitleSetID` should be populated automatically a key of Parent, while we saving child collection